# Using passport of country of nationality after being granted refugee status

Tags: eu, refugees

I hold refugee status in the EU and I have a refugee travel document under the 1951 convention. I want to visit a specific country but this country doesn't accept refugee travel documents.

If I used the passport of my country of nationality, I wouldn't need a visa to travel to this country, but my passport is expired.  If I renew my passport at the embassy and use it for traveling, would it affect my refugee status in EU?

Comment: Generally, that is one of the certain ways to lose refugee status.

Comment: Are you really acknowledged as a refugee under the provision of the UN Refugee Convention (which is actually quite uncommon in the EU) or are you acknowledged for subsidiary protection under directive 2011/95/EU? In both situations, you are colloquially called a 'refugee' but the difference is very relevant for your question.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo At least for Germany your statement that protection based on the UN Refugee Convention is quite uncommon is false. According to the BAMF (the German supreme authority for migration and refugees) in 2015 only 0,6% of the application were rules as subsidiary protection, whereas 48,5% where ruled based on the UN Refugee Convention and the German constitution (see https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/DE/Downloads/Infothek/Statistik/Asyl/statistik-anlage-teil-4-aktuelle-zahlen-zu-asyl.pdf?__blob=publicationFile for the stats)

Comment: the veery general answer here is "of course not".  But moreover it's one of those questions where the answer is, for goodness sake, seek professional advice.

Comment: I indicated that in my answer, but dear OP, if you would include your country of origin and the country you wish to travel to we could give you even better, more specific advice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends, but most likely it is a very bad idea. First of all you have to realize that there is no *"refugee status in the EU"*. Instead, you have been given the refugee status by some specific country (which itself is a member of the European Union). Many laws regarding refugees are defined by national laws and on top of that are some EU laws (especially the Dublin Regulation), so whether what you are doing is a bad idea depends on the country which issued your refugee travel documents.

However, it is *most likely* a very bad idea, because internationally it is well established that a refugee status can be revoked when you return to the protection of the country you were seeking refugee from. But again, this has to be established in the individual laws of the country, so to say for sure we would have to know which country you currently live in.

I can explain the example for Germany, the most populous country within the EU. I would suspect most (if not all) other European countries having similar laws. In [§72 AsylG Absatz 1 Satz 1](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asylvfg_1992/__72.html) it says:

> Die Anerkennung als Asylberechtigter und die Zuerkennung der Flüchtlingseigenschaft erlöschen, wenn der Ausländer sich freiwillig durch Annahme oder Erneuerung eines Nationalpasses oder durch sonstige Handlungen erneut dem Schutz des Staates, dessen Staatsangehörigkeit er besitzt, unterstellt

which roughly translates to

> The refugee status is void, if the foreigner voluntarily accepts or renews their passport or in any other way seeks the protection of the country of origin.

So to be clear: If you received your refugee status in Germany the action you proposed would **definitely result in losing your refugee status**. To be absolutely clear, this will certainly happen as the law explicitly does not define any special circumstances or "may" clauses - It is the only possible legal outcome.

I would also like to address your initial statement that you can't travel to this particular country because it does not recognize your travel document. However, all countries which ratified the 1951 or 1967 Convention should in fact recognize your documents. Wikipedia has a nice map showing these countries, with only the gray states not having joined the Conventions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees#/media/File:Refugeeconvention.PNG
And even these states could still recognize your documents. The refugee travel documents are internationally widely accepted. Hence, I am a bit unconvinced that this country really does not recognize the document at all. However, it might be a lot more cumbersome (e.g. with your other passport you could travel visa free).

If you really want to travel to this country you should consult a lawyer how you could achieve that. But the way you proposed is not a good idea, given its possible drastic consequences.

Comment: Germany is the biggest country of the eu by what means? I wasn't aware of that. ^^

Comment: @Zaibis sorry, I meant the most populous country. I just included this to stress the fact even the OP might not be in Germany, Germany still has some relevance in the EU - Not saying small countries are worse in any aspect, but given the political nature of the EU I guess German legislature is more important than that of many small countries.

Comment: As a counterpoint to this, in the United States, the law 8 USC 1158(c)(2)(D) explicitly says that asylum will terminate if the asylee "voluntarily availed himself or herself of the protection of the alien’s country of nationality ... by returning to such country with permanent resident status ...". It would have been easy for Congress to use a broader phrasing so one would assume that "lesser" acts such as returning _temporarily_ or renewing one's passport at the consulate will _not_ automatically terminate asylum in the U.S.

Comment: This of course does not say anything directly about countries that are neither Germany nor USA, but it does demonstrate that different countries handle things in different ways. I don't think how Germany does things carries any particular (even inspirational) force in the rest of the EU; national legislatures tend to jealously guard their competence to decide such things for themselves.

Comment: I don't think the answer is necessarily incorrect but the preamble isn't quite right and suggests you don't really know the law on this subject. There is actually a lot of EU law (a string of directives and extensive case law from the EU court of justice) on asylum, of which the Dublin system is just a small part. To me it makes more sense to say that national law comes on top of that (and it can only be more – but not less – protective than EU law) rather than the other way around.

Comment: @Relaxed Well, I think your statement that I don't know the law on the subject is quite a harsh judgement and I wonder from what you think you know what I do or don't know. Of course there are more EU laws than Dublin regarding refugees, but there is also _a lot_ defined by the individual countries. And the european standarization process is simply very minimal regarding refugees, their status and their rights. It is not really relevant what is on top of what, they are simply intertwined.

Comment: @dirkk Simply said, EU law's role in this area is definitely *not* minimal (it's obviously implemented through national law but that's simply the way most EU law works in general). That's also why I allowed myself to provoke a little by saying you did not know much about it because I genuinely can't see how you could still write something like that if you were familiar with EU law on the matter. Case in point, it's a very small detail in your answer but “some EU law (especially the Dublin regulation)" is flatly wrong and very revealing.

Comment: The Dublin system is now implemented in a regulation, which means you won't find a German statute with the same contents because regulations are directly applicable and that may be the source of the confusion. But Dublin is really a minor part of EU law on asylum. The bulk of it is defined in three directives and German law has to comply with that. This is not a complete harmonisation but those directives are very extensive and much more significant (and then the Return Directive is also somewhat relevant).

Comment: See [there](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/asylum/index_en.htm) for a starting point if you're interested in reading up on it.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for teaching me. However, you are reading things into my statements which are simply not there - I never said EU laws in this area are minimal and I simply said many things are defined in national law. Although you seem to think the refugee process is standardized within Europe, the reality, especially comparing the living conditions from refugees in different countries such as Sweden or Greece or Germany and Italy prove you wrong.

Comment: @dirkk Now, I think you are the one twisting my words, living conditions are indeed very different and even more importantly the decisions themselves are *very very* different (almost unbelievably so if you look at the stats). But the *process* is, in fact, standardised. And you wrote, “And the european standarization process is simply very minimal”. I am not reading anything special into that statement, it's simply inaccurate, as is the “some EU laws (especially the Dublin Regulation)” in the first paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Most importantly, the stuff that differ the most, like living conditions are *not* defined in national laws, it's a matter of practice. On the other hand, all the stuff you read in national statutes mostly implements (and must comply with) EU law, there is no contradiction here. Bringing that up repeatedly also betrays a lack of understanding.

Comment: I guess we have to agree to disagree. If you think my answer is incorrect you are free to downvote and/or to write a better answer. I honestly see no reason to continue this discussion.

Answer (score 36):

I'd be very careful and seek legal advice before doing this, perhaps from a local organization that assists refugees. In Canada, seeking protection, even just a new passport, from the country a refugee has fled can be [cause to lose refugee protection](http://yourlegalrights.on.ca/common-question/how-can-refugee-lose-their-status-canada). I haven't been able to find a definitive source that indicates the same applies in Europe (and it may depend on who is processing your application), but the underlying international law poses a concern for what you propose to do.

This is because the UN Refugee Convention of 1951 "shall cease to apply to any person if...He has voluntarily re-availed himself of the protection of the country of his nationality." Going to the embassy and renewing your passport could well be considered to be seeking protection from the country of your nationality, which could be grounds to lose your status as a refugee.

Comment: Well, "in Europe" does not really apply here as the refugee laws are heavily defined by the individual countries. However, I would assume in this aspect most of them are quite similar. At least in Germany I can confirm it is basically the same as Canada. §72 AsylG Absatz 1 Satz 1 (see https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asylvfg_1992/__72.html) says you lose the refugee status if you voluntarily accept or renew the passport of your country of origin.

Comment: @dirkk Your comment is the best answer here.  If you can post it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: Agreed. If you don't post it as an answer, I'll incorporate it into mine.

Comment: I would think even if renewing a passport didn't invalidate the refugee status, travelling under that passport to a third country (different from both the passport issuer and refugee issuer) would almost certainly do so.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, I was to lazy to do so. But by your request I overcame my laziness and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 7):

The definition of a [convention](http://www1.umn.edu/humanrts/instree/v1crs.htm) refugee:

> owing to a well-founded fear of being persecuted for reasons of race, religion, nationality, membership of a particular social group or political opinion, is outside the country of his nationality, and is unable to or, owing to such fear, is unwilling to avail himself of the protection of that country or return there because there is a fear of persecution

If you think you are OK with just walking into the embassy of your country then where is the "well-founded fear of persecution"?

Comment: There are a lot of refugees right now, who fled not because of persecution by their government, but rather because of war and the atrocities being committed by combatants.  They may well still support their government but are unable to return due to war and the invading forces.

Comment: @Tom - some might even suspect that most refugees are of that category. But evidently those are not necessarily *convention refugees*

Comment: Indeed, as @Tom says, people might flee war rather than their own government.  Also, even if someone fears arrest and torture from country *X*, that doesn't mean that there is a direct threat from country *X* embassy in country *Y*, depending on how powerful the secret service for country *X* is.  I doubt they have torture chambers at the embassy.

Comment: @CMaster - One might guess that countries have some leeway in granting refugee status beyond what is specified in the convention documents.

Comment: Well, what other refugees are there if not convention refugees? Here's the German http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_asylvfg/englisch_asylvfg.html#p0020 law: "A foreigner is a refugee as defined in the Convention of 28 July 1951 on the legal status of refugees". I understand the plight of of those fleeing from Libya or Syria but where's the legal ground?

Comment: @chx Most EU countries (I think except UK, Ireland and Denmark) have ratified directive 2011/95/EU, which grants subsidiary protection to persons who are not covered by the UN Refugee Convention, but who fear 'the death penalty or execution; or torture or inhuman or degrading treatment or punishment of an applicant in the country of origin; or serious and individual threat to a civilian’s life or person by reason of indiscriminate violence in situations of international or internal armed conflict' if returned to his home country. These are usually also called 'refugees' in colloquial language.

Comment: I am not versed in international law, but does a "convention" mandate exact following or are they more minimum standards that countries have agreed to.  In other words can a country's laws on refugees only cover those defined in the convention or can they cover both those who are defined as well as others they deem to be "refugees"?  Tor-Einar's comment would seem to point to the later.

Comment: @chx There are many different types of refugee status in Germany. "convention refugees" (usually called GFK-Flüchtling, GFK standing for _Geneva refugee confention_). However, there is one even better status (refugee as based on the German constitution §16a) or other refugee status such as the mentioned subsidiary protection or even national deportation ban. They all have different results for the person, especially in the context of being allowed to work, for taking integration/language courses or reuniting with your family.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Interesting.  I am trying to reconcile the concepts of "individual threat" and "indiscriminate violence."

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Member states don't “ratify” directives, they implement them. And they cannot, in principle, pick and choose if they want to do it or not, they are bound to do it within a certain delay. What Denmark, the UK and Ireland have is a special opt-in/opt-ou mechanism for what used to be the third pillar of the EU (matters related to police and justice). IIRC, the UK did opt-in to some of the asylum directives.

Comment: @Tom Your understanding is exactly right, both the Geneva convention and EU directives define minimum standards.